# For loop will not initialize?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

Hello i am trying to loop through a set of buttons and then identify the id of that particular button.

For some reason the for loop will not run.

```js
function checkButton() {
 var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("deleteButton");

 for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    dog_id = e.target.dataset.id; 
    console.log(dog_id);
    ProcessDeleteRequest();
   }, false);
 }
}
```

Comment: Please add the HTML as well as it's hard to help with just one part of the possibly entire issue

Comment: You could use `debugger` or `console.log(buttons.length)` to find out if the buttons are there.

Comment: didn't even think of that ;) . well it is showing 0 so i guess that answers my problem. Thanks